# Angular 2 reactive form conditional validation getting error

Tags: angular

I am new in angular 2. I am facing an issue when I conditionally validate a field.I have a selection box and there is few options along with other.When some one change to other then a text box will be open and it is a required field.After touching the other text box if any one does not write any thing then it thrown a validation error.That is working fine.But after getting the error if I change to other option the required validation for the other text box remain exist. That's why can't submit the form.

## HTML

```
<label for="sel1">Author Name:</label>
<select (change)="changeExistingAuthorIdName()" placeholder="Select Author" class="form-control" id="authorNameNewList" formControlName="authorNameNewList">
  <option *ngFor="let authorIdNameEach of authorIdName" [ngValue]="authorIdNameEach">{{authorIdNameEach.authorname}}</option>
  <option [ngValue]="otherAuthorList">Other</option>
</select>
<mat-error *ngIf="newBookForm.controls.authorNameNewList.touched &&                        newBookForm.controls.authorNameNewList.hasError('required')"> Please Select Author
</mat-error>
<div class="row" *ngIf="otherAuthorInput">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label for="sel1">Enter Author Name:</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="authorNameNew" class="form-
            control" id="authorNameNew">
    <mat-error *ngIf="newBookForm.controls.authorNameNew.touched &&                           newBookForm.controls.authorNameNew.hasError('required')"> Please Enter Author Name
    </mat-error>
  </div>
</div>
```

## TS

```
constructor(private _DashboardService: DashboardService, private fv: FormBuilder) {
  this.fb = fv;
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.newBookForm = this.fb.group({
    bookNameNew: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    authorNameNewList: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    categoryNew: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
  })

}
otherAuthorInput = false;
otherAuthorList = {
  id: 99,
  authorname: 99
};
changeExistingAuthorIdName() {
  if (this.newBookForm.value.authorNameNewList.id == 99) {
    this.otherAuthorInput = true;
    // this.newBookForm.get('authorNameNew').setValidators([Validators.required]);
    this.newBookForm.get('authorNameNew').setValidators([Validators.required]);
  } else {
    this.otherAuthorInput = false;
    this.newBookForm.get('authorNameNew').clearValidators();
  }
  this.newBookForm.get('authorNameNew').updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

All the validation working fine except other.
It giving me the error "Cannot read property 'setValidators' of null" when I change to other. Actually what I am looking for is that when some one select other then the input text will have required validator. otherwise no validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to declare authorNameNew as FormControl, in your FormGroup

```
  this.newBookForm = this.fb.group({
    bookNameNew: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    authorNameNewList: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    categoryNew: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    authorNameNew: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
  })
```

If you have a FormControl that's not required, don't add Validators.required.. in example: authorNameNew

```
  this.newBookForm = this.fb.group({
    bookNameNew: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    authorNameNewList: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    categoryNew: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    authorNameNew: ['']
  })
```

Comment: But in this case no error is given. But suppose I choose others and I touch other text box and did not write anything.Then it gives required error.And its normal.But the error remain after changing the other to any option value

Comment: @Rahul, get rid of the Validators.required in places you don't require input. It's an optional validation step

Comment: I can't get you. As I am new in this field. Can you elaborate or give a sample? It will be very helpful. Please don't mind.

Comment: I do the same.Now no error is given. But if required validator once triggered it is not destroyed. But it should destroy when I change the option value.

Comment: I didn't understand that. Are you saying the validation requirement is still there? Refresh page

Comment: @ Iancovici  Now its working. My observation was wrong. Thank you so much for helping me. Thanks a lot.